# Establish connection to db2 using the jt400.jar

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, jt400, jtopen

I have tried using the db2jcc.jar and I successfully establish connection to db2 but now I am trying to use the jt400.jar

I have tried to use the driver com.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver but I keep getting the class not found exception.

I tried using the com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver but I can't establish connection.

Can anyone help me or provide a sample code with the connection string connecting to a db2 with jt400.jar.

```
Class.forName("com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver");
Properties prop = new Properties();

prop.setProperty("user", "current");
prop.setProperty("password", "current");

con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:as400://server/database", prop);
```

Comment: What exception do you get?   Are you connecting to an IBM i?   Have you started the hosts servers on the IBM i?

Comment: i keep getting the java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect. I have a db2 database installed in my pc. I have successfully connected to my db2 using the db2jcc.jar but now I want to try to connect to my db2 using the jt400.jar.

Comment: jt400.jar can only connect to DB2 on IBM i (aka AS/400).  It does not connect to DB2 for windows, unix, linux, or z.

Comment: thanks for the information. I was hoping it would work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use this code to connect to my db2 database with jt400 :

```
Class.forName("com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:as400:" + iseries + ";database name=" + iasp + ";prompt=false;translate binary=true;naming=system", login, password);
```

For exemple, if I try to connect to the server "server1" and the database "database1", the url is "jdbc:as400:server1;database name=database1;prompt=false;translate binary=true;naming=system"

Comment: @YLombardi, the "server1" here has to be an IBM iSeries server? I am asking because I am not able to connect to "DB2 installed on my MacOS using docker".

Comment: @PranavKevadiya, Yes for me it was an IBM iSeries server.

Comment: Thanks @YLombardi, that answers my question. :)

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late to this party but just wanted to point out a tutorial that might aid others when using Spring Framework and connecting to a DB2 dataSource.   In my example, I was using Tomcat Server but it should be applicable to other web servers as well.   Anyways, I hope this helps:  https://avaldes.com/spring-mvc-with-jndi-datasource-for-db2-on-as400-using-tomcat/

Comment: If possible, cite the most relevant parts, even if it's your blog. URL's go down and the knowledge in answers should be preserved.

Comment: Good idea.  Will do.

Comment: `    <bean id=”dataSource” class=”org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource” >
<property name=”driverClassName” value=”com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver” />
<property name=”url” value=”jdbc:as400://devAS400.avaldes.com:50000/TUTORIALS” />
<property name=”username” value=”webuser” />
<property name=”password” value=”webuser” />
</bean>`

Comment: You can also set up a configuration bean instead of XML config.

Comment: `@Configuration
 public class dataSourceConfiguration {
  // get config from properties files
  ...
  
  dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
    dataSource.setUrl(url);
    dataSource.setUsername(username);
    dataSource.setPassword(password);
     
    return dataSource;
  }`